# parameter parsed to SHA1 in BSF processor ( javascript) of jmeter throws error

Tags: javascript, jmeter, sha1

I've a scenario like

```
 user logs in ( /login)

 navigate to the reservations page to get all the reservation id (/reservations)

  Through regular expression I retrieve all reservation ids like reservationids_1=19678406 etc...

  navigate to the first reservation id (/reservation/${reservationids_1})
```

In every page it navigates , the HTTP header manager needs the handShakeKey applicable to that page which is basically combination of url, secretKey, publicKey. ( secretKey , publicKey are both static but url changes )

For static urls like ( /login, /reservations) I've added a BSF pre-processor at beginning and declare variables and use those variables in the HTTP Header Manager as ${handshakeKey_reservations}, ${handshakeKey_login} etc which  works perfectly fine.

```
  var urls = ["login", "reservations", "logout", "profile"];

  for (var i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) {

    var handShakeKeyForStaticUrls = CryptoJS.SHA1("/"+urls[i]+"abcdediiebneC"+"12345678");

      handShakeKeyForStaticUrls = handShakeKeyForStaticUrls.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64);

     vars.put("handshakeKey_"+urls[i], handShakeKeyForStaticUrls);

      }
```

Now the problem is for Dynamic url (/reservation/${reservationid}, /reservation/${reservationid}/summary etc.......)

As a work around I tried to put a BSF post processor before every dynamic url HTTTP sampler

```
//reservationid = "19678406";

reservationid = "${reservationids_1}";

vars.put ("val", reservationid);

vars.put ("type", typeof(reservationid));

 var handShakeKeyForDynamicUrls = CryptoJS.SHA1( "/reservation/" + reservationid +"abcdeeee"+"12345678"); 

 handShakeKeyForDynamicUrls = handShakeKeyForDynamicUrls.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64); 

 vars.put("handShakeKeyForDynamicUrls", handShakeKeyForDynamicUrls);
```

In the HTTP header manager I am using handshakeKey  ${handShakeKeyForDynamicUrls}

When I am using reservationid = "19678406" as hard coded in BSF sampler ( javascript);

its working fine as example

```
 GET https://<servername>/reservation/19678406
 handshake key :- 21d1ce663d079b5583d76730f6f1477d8f6ae
 Also in the debug sampler type and val coming as string and 19678406 which is OK
```

However When I am using reservationid = "${reservationids_1}" in BSF sampler ( javascript) ; it fails

```
  GET https://<servername>/reservation/19678406
  handshake key :- b607876d69f5d59c5258bcd5a2a064bbcf35
 Also in the debug sampler type and val coming as string and 19678406
```

So don't understand how both are different. Why its getting failed. Instead of hard coded value if I pass an parameter ( having string type and value same in both cases) why its getting failed.

Any thought on this ??

Note:- There is no error in the log viewer.

Answer (score 0):

I did a workaround and it worked fine.

Added another BSF sampler ( BeanShell) before that and mentioned like

```
vars.put ("reservationid", "${reservationid_1}");
```

then the next BSF post processor ( java script)

```
 var handShakeKeyForDynamicUrls = CryptoJS.SHA1( "/reservation/${reservationid}" +"abcdeeee"+"12345678"); 

handShakeKeyForDynamicUrls = handShakeKeyForDynamicUrls.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64); 

vars.put("handShakeKeyForDynamicUrls", handShakeKeyForDynamicUrls);
```